# 500 error when trying to add new order in TradeGecko API

Tags: php, post, oauth-2.0

Pretty specific problem, but I'll lay it out as best I can.

I can easily make a POST request to the TradeGecko API (detailed here: http://developer.tradegecko.com/) and get variant prices in return, that part of the interaction is working smoothly.

However, I'm trying to create a new order and I feel like I'm missing something!

Here's what I have:

```
<?php
$authorizeUrl = 'https://api.tradegecko.com/oauth/authorize';
$accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.tradegecko.com/oauth/token';
$clientId = <MY_CLIENT_ID>;
$clientSecret = <MY_CLIENT_SECRET>;
$redirectUrl = <REDIRECT_URI>;

// https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2

require("Client.php");
require("GrantType/IGrantType.php");
require("GrantType/AuthorizationCode.php");
$client = new OAuth2\Client($clientId, $clientSecret, OAuth2\Client::AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_BASIC);
$client->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$userAgent);
$client->setAccessToken(<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>);
$client->setAccessTokenType(OAuth2\Client::ACCESS_TOKEN_BEARER);
$params = 
array('order' => 
    array( 
        'company_id' => '12345',
        'shipping_address_id' => 1,
        'billing_address_id' => 1,
        'status' => 'active',
        'issued_at' => '10-04-2016',
        'order_line_items' => array(
            array('variant_id' => 123456,
                'quantity' => 2),
            array('variant_id' => 123457,
                'quantity' => 2)
            )
    )
);

$response = $client->fetch('https://api.tradegecko.com/orders', false, $params); 
print_r($response);
?>
```

I'm hoping that there's something in that code that someone else might spot, I've been staring at it for the better part of 6 hours now, and I can't figure out why this won't go through.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?